# Where or where clauses not working good in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i was confused by this where clsuses, i have this code, i called the past orders. Its working fine for now.

```
$orders = Order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->orWhere(function ($query2) {
                $query2->where('status', '=', 2)
                      ->where('status', '=', 3);
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

then i have a foreach below that code. Then i have another where variable:

```
$orders_current = Order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->orWhere(function ($query) {
                $query->where('status', '=', 0)
                      ->where('status', '=', 1);
            })
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();
```

And from now all the foreach results looks weird, it showing all the data with all status in each data current and past. Do i have to move one of the code above to another method or there is another ways to avoid this? and what is exactly happened here, please explain.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$orders_current = Order::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
        ->where(function ($query) {
            $query->where('status', '=', 0)
                  ->OrWhere('status', '=', 1);
        })
        ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

I hope that will help you..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the `where` and `orWhere` methods mixed up. The first one adds an `AND` clause to the `WHERE` statement, while the second one adds an `OR` clause.

That means the resulting queries are:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE user_id = ?
  OR (status = 0 AND status = 1)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

The second part of the `OR` will never be true, and you are probably just seeing all of the user orders in each of both queries.

You can always use the [getQueryLog](http://www.goodbytes.be/blog/article/log-last-executed-eloquent-query-as-plain-sql-in-laravel-5) method in order to see how the SQL query is formed.